# jQuery height issues when content is displayed in an iFrame in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, iframe, height

I am working on a calendar/schedule that requires breaks to span the full height of the containing event. The below code works great in FF/Chrome and IE. The issue arises when loading the content via an iFrame in Firefox, the height is always set to zero. The page will only display correctly when the iFrame is reloaded.

[here is DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fBTeg/3)

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".event").each(function () {
        var height = $(this).height();
        $(".note, .break").each(function () {
            $(this).height(height);
        });
    });
})
```

I am looking for a consistent solution or a workaround for FF so that the heights are applied correctly on first load of the iFrame.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added an example on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fBTeg/3/

Answer (score 0):

way 1: wrap your iframe with a div got float:left; and calculate div's height on fireforx.

try to calculate this div's height, not iframe's..

```
<div style="float:left">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

[.load() usage](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

way2:

```
$(document).ready(function () {//if u wont define more specific element, use docment ready
    $(".event").each(function () {
        var height = $(this).height();
        $(".note, .break").each(function () {
            $(this).css('height':height+'px');//to change css height
            //$(this).attr('height',height);//to change inline attr height
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: I was using document ready previously and changed to the load() event in case it was a timing issue. Your solution has the same results as I am already experiencing unfortunately.

Comment: did u tried to wrap your iframe with a div got float:left; and calculate div's height on fireforx?

Comment: The issue is not with the iFrame height, the issue is in the page loaded into the iFrame and only when it is displayed in an iFrame. I've added an example (see OP above) of the page being displayed in an iFrame.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fBTeg/6/ its alerting different values, and i checked on firefox too, same variables 72 96 169, u cant give diffrenet value to height,

Comment: It will do and this is correct, there are 3 events on there and so you get 3 heights with your alerts addition. The heights are only applied to the elements with .break or .note classes inside of each .event. E.g. event 1 breaks are set to the height of the first event container. and so on and so forth.

Comment: i checked with ie, chrome and firefox12 , its (breaks) all same on my computer //: sorry cant understand ur problem /:

Comment: On my original example on Chrome and FF 13.0.1 see this url http://fiddle.jshell.net/fBTeg/3/show/ You should see that the red and navy blue blocks (with .note or .break classes applied) will span the full height of the containing div which has .event class applied.